# iOS 7.1 - Where do emails go to when I 'archive' them in Gmail App?

Tags: email, gmail, iphone, ios

I have iOS 7.1 installed on my iPhone and I am using the built in Gmail app.   If I am in the inbox and I mark a few messages, I swear I used to have an option to move the marked items to the trash.   Now I get (across the bottom of the screen)

[image]

My question is, where do emails actually go when I select Archive?   I would assume they would go into some folder somewhere, but what i really want is to move them to the trash.   I could always click Move, and then select the folder - but I seem to rarely remember to do this.   There were a few messages I 'archived' that I can no longer seem to find.   As a test, I selected a few messages and archived them, and afterwards they do not seem to show up in the trash or in any of the main email folders on my account.

### [image]

Comment: Pedantically, this is the built in mail app, not the built in gmail app.  It operates the same way with archive as web gmail does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to delete the emails, you can just hold your finger on the "Archive" button for a second or two, and choose "Trash selected messages".

@shub's answer is correct as per the original question, though. (SO won't let me comment yet, or this would just be a comment.)

Comment: I switched the answer to your reply - since this is actually what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 8):

When you archive things in gmail, it just removes the 'inbox' label on it. If you want to find the archived email, just search for them or you can click on the label 'all mail' on the left. The same goes with gmail online. see more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576?hl=en

Comment: nice, keep them coming

Comment: `it just removes any labels on it`. This is not true, right? It just removes the `inbox` label. If you would have applied different labels on the message (e.g. `boss`, `work`, `invite`) while it was in the inbox, those labels will still be applied to the message when you archive it.

Comment: @BartArondson That is true, sorry, I'll edit it now - thanks for pointing that error out to me

Answer (score 0):

I found them in the label "important"

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Apple documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202067):

> When you archive a message, it moves to the All Mail folder. Mail doesn't delete the message from the Gmail account. Using the Archive setting replaces all delete options, including tapping the Trash icon while you view a message, and selecting Edit to manage multiple messages.

Mostly important, turning it off will make you delete the messages instead of archiving:

> To turn off Archive, go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Gmail Account > Account > Advanced > Move Discarded Messages Into.

Answer (score 0):

I created a Smart Mailbox with the following parameters:

*Message is not in Mailbox: Inbox*

Once I did that, it provided me all of the emails that I have archived.  Have fun!